# 301 error after changing WordPress domain

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I tried moving a site on a development domain to it's production domain. I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS and Nginx 1.14.0

How I did the move: First I added the correct IP to the new domain in the admin panel for my domain registrar 
I then updated to the correct URL in the WordPress admin dashboard. 
I then ran certbot `sudo certbot --nginx -d oslopeace19.no` to get the correct certificates for my site.

But when I tested the site nginx redirects me to the default site instead of the site I set up.

I've debugged for almost a full day, now I've removed the HTTPS certs, but I'm still getting the same error. the weird thing is that when I run `curl -v http://oslopeace19.no` I get the message

```
...
< X-Redirect-By: WordPress
...
```

This leads me to think that WordPress is doing something weird here. To try and solve this I've set

```
define('WP_HOME','http://oslopeace19.no');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://oslopeace19.no');
define('RELOCATE', true);
```

in `wp-config.php` and manually verified that the correct URL is set for siteurl and home in the wordpress database.

Nginx conf:

```
server {

   listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
    #Logger
    access_log /var/log/nginx/oslopeace19;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_oslopeace19;
    #Sikkerhet
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    server_tokens off;
    index index.php;

    ## Begin - Server Info
    root /var/www/oslopeace19;
    server_name oslopeace19.no;
    ## End - Server Info

    ## Begin - Index
    # for subfolders, simply adjust the rewrite:
    # to use `/subfolder/index.php`
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    ## End - Index
location = /.user.ini { deny all; }




    ## Begin - PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Choose either a socket or TCP/IP address
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    ## End - PHP

    ## Begin - Security
    # deny all direct access for these folders
    location ~* /(.git|cache|bin|logs|backups)/.*$ { return 403; }
    # deny running scripts inside core system folders
    location ~* /(system|vendor)/.*\.(txt|xml|md|html|yaml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
    # deny running scripts inside user folder
    location ~* /user/.*\.(txt|md|yaml|php|pl|py|cgi|twig|sh|bat)$ { return 403; }
    # deny access to specific files in the root folder
    location ~ /(LICENSE|composer.lock|composer.json|nginx.conf|web.config|htaccess.txt|\.htaccess) { return 403; }
    ## End - Security


}
```

Site URL is oslopeace19.no, any suggestions?

Comment: Your site seems to be on HTTPS, not HTTP. Please update your question with the actual state of your server and nginx configuration.

Comment: this config cant meet the current working site?!